# SQL server not able to stop on windows 8 ... please help ... using sqlserver 2000 on windows 8 home

Tags: windows-8, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am currently using a software which is dependent on SQL server 2000. However whenever i try to exit the program and try to stop the SQL server i get a message--  An error 5 (access denied) occurred. Currently using windows 8 home. The SQL server came bundled with the software. Is there any fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Error 5 is saying you don't have authority to do what you are trying to do. You need to log in to the machine as Administrator to stop the SQL service (under Administrative Tools in Control Panel).  You might also try the Services tab in Task Manager by right clicking on it.